# Keycloak access_token valid after logout api call

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I m new to keycloak, after calling logout api, I m able to access the api's even after logout.
It is accessible till the time access_token is valid. Ideally after log out the access token should be invalid and user should not be able to call the apis.
Can any one please help me how to revoke access token by calling keycloak api or any other workarround.

Comment: Do you use openid-connect?

Comment: Yes I m using openid-connect

Answer (score 0):

Your API has to support `Back-Channel Logout` and of course `Backchannel Logout URL` must be properly configured on the Keycloak client config side. BTW: Keycloak supports backchannel logout from the recent version 12.0.0.

Your API will be "notified" when IdP (Keycloak) receives any logout request, so it can processed and it can block any further request even if the user token is still valid. Keep it in the mind: in must supported by your API code.

Another option is to keep very short lifetime for access token. It is pretty normal to have 5 minute lifetime. In that case expected the "logout" will be based on the token expiration.